# SQL - Only able to add null values using INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am currently looking to input a load of dummy information to a database I've created.

This is one of the tables:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
CREATE TABLE Staff
(
Staff_ID            INTEGER(5) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
Local_ID            INTEGER(5), 
First_name          VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Last_name           VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Email               VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Telephone           INTEGER(15) NOT NULL,
Date_employed           DATE NOT NULL,
Salary              DECIMAL NOT NULL,
Sales_ID            INTEGER(5),
Manager_ID          INTEGER(5),
Development_ID          INTEGER(5),
FOREIGN KEY (Local_ID)      REFERENCES LocalOffice(Local_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Sales_ID)      REFERENCES Sales_Advisors(Sales_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Manager_ID)    REFERENCES Site_Manager(Manager_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Development_ID)    REFERENCES Development(Development_ID)
);
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

And this is the only way I can submit data:

```
INSERT INTO Staff VALUES 
(null, null, 'Sean', 'D', 'UP62@mac.uk', '07411557877', '2012-10-08', 80000.00,null,null,null);
```

If i try and put int values instead: I get:

```
INSERT INTO Staff VALUES 
(null,1, 'Luke', 'Clifford', 'UP624715@myport.ac.uk', '07411557077', '2012-10-08', 80000.00,1,1,1);
```

ERROR:

```
 #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`happy_homes`.`staff`, CONSTRAINT `staff_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
(`Local_ID`) REFERENCES `localoffice` (`Local_ID`))
```

Can anyone help

Comment: Do you have any data in LocalOffice, Sales_Advisors, Site_Manager and Development tables?

Comment: When you try to insert into stuff you put in a NULL-value, but the foreign keys want a reference to the localoffe-table?

Comment: It's considered bad (SQL) coding style to *not* list the column names in the insert statement

Answer (score 1):

INSERT first data inside `LocalOffice` table after that your query will work. The integer value should be present inside `LocalOffice` table before inserting in `Staff` table.

It clearly says that it is foreign key

```
FOREIGN KEY (Local_ID)      REFERENCES LocalOffice(Local_ID)
```